# "Send Email Compaign Message" action is not working when I select DropdownListField as SelectEmailField

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am using sitecore 10.3 and working with sitecore forms "Send Email Compaign Message" Action. it is working and e-mails are sent when I select "Email" Field but it is not working when I select "DropDownList" Field as below
[image]

I need to send to different admin E-mails based on value of "DropDownList" value that selected. so i added the E-mail adresses as values in dynamic datasource

[image]

but when I submit the emails are not sent. I tried to add token for dropdownlist to see its value and it is coming in array like ["email@email.com"]

I do know if this the error or what, any ideas how to fix this ??

Comment: You need to write custom logic to fetch the data from the drop-down list

Comment: ok but how to send it to "send email compaign message" action, or you mean to create custom action to send mail

Comment: you need to create a custom email action to get the details(email id) from the dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

you need to override GetFieldValue to return the email values as ";" separated

```
class FormsFieldValueResolver : Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.Actions.FormFields.FormsFieldValueResolver
{
    public override object GetFieldValue(IViewModel fieldViewModel)
    {
        Condition.Requires(fieldViewModel, nameof(fieldViewModel)).IsNotNull();
        if (fieldViewModel is TextViewModel textViewModel)
            return textViewModel.Text;
        else if (fieldViewModel is DropDownListViewModel listViewModel)
            return string.Join(";", listViewModel.Value).Trim(';');
        return fieldViewModel.GetType().GetProperty("Value")?.GetValue(fieldViewModel);
    }
}
```

donot forget to use your new implementation through Dependency Injection

```
    public class ServiceConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator
{
    public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        Condition.Requires<IServiceCollection>(serviceCollection, nameof(serviceCollection)).IsNotNull<IServiceCollection>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IFormsFieldValueResolver, [YourNameSpace].FormsFieldValueResolver>();

    }
}
```